# kthread_run doesn't have CLONE_FILES behaviour

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was digging through the source of `kthread_run` in Linux 4.15.0. Following the sequence of calls it leads to [`create_thread`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/kernel/kthread.c#L261), which calls `kernel_thread` as follows -

```
pid = kernel_thread(kthread, create, CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | SIGCHLD);
```

The clone_flags have `CLONE_FILES` set, which means that the created thread should share the file descriptor table with the current thread.

But when I print `current->files` from the original thread and the spawned thread, they have different values. I understand that kernel threads should not run in process context and *should* not share the file descriptor table, but why is the `CLONE_FILES` flag being ignored here?

I dug further and found that CLONE_FILES is used here - https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/kernel/fork.c#L1740

```
retval = copy_files(clone_flags, p);
```

Which does the following -

```
static int copy_files(unsigned long clone_flags, struct task_struct *tsk)
{
    struct files_struct *oldf, *newf;
    int error = 0;

    /*
     * A background process may not have any files ...
     */
    oldf = current->files;
    if (!oldf)
        goto out;

    if (clone_flags & CLONE_FILES) {
        atomic_inc(&oldf->count);
        goto out;
    }

    newf = dup_fd(oldf, &error);
    if (!newf)
        goto out;

    tsk->files = newf;
    error = 0;
out:
    return error;
}
```

Clearly both the task structs should share the files field if the CLONE_FILES is set.

Comment: Why don't you just replace `goto out;` with `return error;`?

Comment: @Lundin this is not my code, this is the implementation in the Linux kernel. I am just referencing it here to say that the files should not be duplicated when `CLONE_FILES` is set

Comment: Sigh. Yeah well that explains it... Although, from the (hobbyist quality) Linux kernel coding style document, emphasis mine: "The goto statement comes in handy when a function exits from multiple locations and some common work such as cleanup has to be done. *If there is no cleanup needed then just return directly.*"

Comment: I think I figured it out. The actual call to `create_thread` is made by `kthreadd` and not the calling thread. As a result it inherits the file descriptor table from `kthreadd`.

Comment: it's funny how after trying to debug this for an hour I figured it only 10 mins after posting the question. I guess I will close the question.

Comment: You can self-answer the question.

Comment: @AKX I should actually do that. There is a chance somebody might stumble upon something similar in the future.

Answer (score 1):

After looking carefully through the source I figured the reason for this discrepancy. Linux uses a separate `kthreadd` mechanism to spawn kernel threads.

The calling thread enqueues the task to be created into a list as follow -

```
spin_lock(&kthread_create_lock);
list_add_tail(&create->list, &kthread_create_list);
spin_unlock(&kthread_create_lock);
```

There is a separate thread running (`kthreadd_task`) which keeps polling this list and dispatches calls to `create_thread` as follows -

```
create = list_entry(kthread_create_list.next,
                        struct kthread_create_info, list);
list_del_init(&create->list);
spin_unlock(&kthread_create_lock);

create_kthread(create);

spin_lock(&kthread_create_lock);
```

This means that the `CLONE_FILES` is actually respected, but it shares the file descriptor table with the `kthreadd` thread.

For this reason, the file descriptor table is not the same as the thread that called `kthread_run`.